# How to convert LINQ query result to list and return generic List?

Tags: linq, generics, data-structures, generic-collections

I used generic ORM list
example.

This is my table.

```
Person table

Guid
Name
LastName
```

and this is my struct class.

```
 public struct PersonItem   // database and class field names are the same
    {
        public Guid   Guid{ get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }


  public struct PersonItems
    {
        public PersonItems()
        {
            Items = new List<PersonItem>();
        }

        public List<PersonItem> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using such and no problem but I always have to write field's

```
public PersonItems GetPersons()
        {
            var query = (from p in _DbEntities.t_Crew
                         select p).ToList();

            if (query != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    _PersonItems.Items.Add(new PersonItem
                        {
                            Guid = item.Guid,
                            Name = item.Name,
                            LastName = item.LastName

                        });
                }
            }

            return _PersonItems;

        }   


   public PersonItems GetPersons()
    {
        PersonItems personItems = new PersonItems();

        var query = from p in _DbEntities.t_Person
                    select p; >> this here query I need to convert linq query result to list

       personItems = query.ToList();
       return personItems ;
    }

error
```

Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List' to PersonData.PersonItems'.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 public PersonItems GetPersons()
    {
        PersonItems personItems = new PersonItems();

        var query = (from p in _DbEntities.t_Person
                    select new PersonItems 
                    {
                        test = p.SomeName,
                        //Other Stuff
                        //...
                    }).ToList();
       return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing to the other version of your `GetPersons()` method, I think this line :

```
personItems = query.ToList();
```

should've been this way instead :

```
personItems.Items = query.ToList();
```

Update regarding the latest error. You can't assign list of `t_Person` to `Item` property which is of type list of `PersonItem`. Hence, your query need to be adjusted to return list of `PersonItem` :

```
var query = from p in _DbEntities.t_Person
            select new PersonItem
                        {
                            Guid = p.Guid,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            LastName = p.LastName
                        };
```

or other option is to change definition of `Item` property to list of `t_Person` :

```
public List<t_Person> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: the same error message?? if it is different please post the latest error message

Comment: yes the same error message..  personItems.Items = query.ToList();     Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<PersonData.t_Person>' to System.Collections.Generic.List<PersonData.Defination.PersonItem>' C:\TFS\Projects\Ship\PersonData\Persons.cs 50 31 PersonData

Comment: check my updated answer. Items property is of different type from what linq query returns, hence you got that conversion error

Answer (score 0):

> **Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List' to PersonData.PersonItems'**

Above error says that you are trying to convert generic list to PersonItems.

So at this line, `query.ToList()` code returns `List<PersonItem>` not the `PersonItems`

```
    var query = from p in _DbEntities.t_Person
                select p; >> this here query I need to convert linq query result to list

   personItems = query.ToList();
   return personItems ;
```

So thats the reason above line of code fails.

Comment: so yes I already tried it...but the same mistake again  List<PersonItem> crewItems = new List<PersonItem>(); and I don't need that,because they already have a List class

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
Change .ctor of PersonItems:

```
public struct PersonItems
{
    public PersonItems(List<PersonItem> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public List<PersonItem> Items { get; set; }
 }
```

And then method GetPersons():

```
public PersonItems GetPersons()
{    
    return new PersonItems(_DbEntities.t_Person.ToList());
}
```

Comment: because sometimes I'm using wcf service and table join,I can not use your proposal